# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\getallemlpoyees.php on line 28 0 results

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a  syntax error on a PHP script:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\getallemlpoyees.php on line 28 0 results

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, FROM employees";


    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo "<br> ID: ".$row["id"]. "- firstname: ".$row["firstname"] ." lastname: ". $row["lastname"] . "<br>";



    }
} 

    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

Comment: Your query is failing due to an extra comma after lastname.  Checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your query would point that out.

Comment: See the duplicate link to find out how to enable mysqli error reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, FROM employees";`

Don't put a comma after `lastname`.